# osx bash force case sensitivity

Tags: macos, bash

```
Me:~ me$ cd desktop
Me:desktop me$ pwd
/Users/me/desktop
```

What is the correct way to force case sensitivity (so that `cd desktop` fails but `cd Desktop` goes to the correct directory)?  I would assume there was a `shopt` for that but the manpage doesn't suggest any obvious option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case-sensitivity is an option of the file system, not of the shell. Therefore you cannot change this with a shell option.

(To understand why, just consider that it is possible to have case-sensitive and case-insensitive filesystems mounted at the same time. How would you handle this with a single shell option?)

Comment: Even if the filesystem is case-insensitive, there's a default rendering for each file.  The filesystem renders the `desktop` folder as if the name is `Desktop`.  Is there a way to force commands to assume that only the default rendering is acceptable?

Comment: The effect that pwd prints the folder name like you entered it (I.e. lowercase), instead of as it is stored in the filesystem (capitalized) is an artifact of the implementation of bash. It just prints the name in the form in which it got it originally from you (via the cd command). I.e., cd doesn't bother to retrieve the correct casing from disk.

Comment: Put another way, as far as `bash` knows, there *is* a directory called `desktop`. If it asks the file system for information about `desktop` (or `DESkToP` or `dESktOP`, or any other variation), the file system complies without giving any indication as the "real" name of the directory.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like filesystem in question is not case-sensitive -- see the first answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22297/is-bash-in-osx-case-insensitive) to verify.

Comment: thats understood, but my question is whether you can force the shell to act as if the filesystem is case sensitive